# Probability question regarding range

Tags: probability

I am stuck with the following question. It is as follows,

```
      | Employed   | UnEmployed   | Total
Male  |   460      |     40       |  500
Female|   140      |    260       |  400
Total |   600      |    300       |  900
```

If the person is selected and the selected person is male, what is the probability that the selected person is employed?

---

Now given are the counts not probability but the solution has used the counts as probabilities. I am confused as probabilities lie between `0` and `1`. Please help out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of an event is is the number of times the event can occur divided by total number of possible events. In your case, you have $500$ males out of which $460$ are employed. So the probability will be $\frac{460}{500}=\frac{23}{25}=0.92$

Comment: Dennis' answer is correct if each person has the same chance of being selected which would be the case if when you say "selected" you mean "selected at random".  The counts are not probabilities but as you can see the solution is a ratio of counts.